# Crash in C++ Code

Tags: c++, crash

I am trying to list all files in a directory recursively. But my code crashes without giving any error. When the given file is directory I recursively call the function or else print its name.

I am using dirent.h

```
int list_file(string path)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    char  *c_style_path;
    c_style_path = new char[path.length()];
    c_style_path = (char *)path.c_str();
    dir = opendir (c_style_path);
    if (dir != NULL) {

        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR && (strcmp(ent->d_name,".")!=0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name,"..")!=0))
            {
                string tmp = path + "\\" + ent->d_name;
                list_file(tmp);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<ent->d_name<<endl;
            }
        }
        closedir (dir);
    } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror ("");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    delete [] c_style_path;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting as to what I am doing wrong here.  Any clues ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the cause:

```
c_style_path = (char *)path.c_str();
//...
delete[] c_style_path;
```

as it is `delete[]`ing memory that it should not and probably results in a double free when `path` goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Just use `path.c_str()` when you require `const char*`:

```
dir = opendir (path.c_str());
```

Note that storing the pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()` is quite dangerous as it can easily lead to a dangling pointer if the `std::string` instance goes out of scope.

Comment: He's also leaking `new char[path.length()]` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks hmjd that helped. But I still have doubt why was it happening, because when I am deleting it I no longer use it.

Comment: Benj how is that leading to a leak ?

Comment: @Ankuj, you did allocate memory for `c_style_path` but you then pointed it to a buffer internal to the `std::string` instance (the assignment did not copy the internal string). The `std::string` instance will delete its buffer when it's destructor is invoked, but the posted code had already deleted it.